# Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism, poynting-vector

So I saw this video from the science asylum youtube channel and that guy said "momentum doesn't require velocity" and "if u have a constant perpendicular electric field and magnetic field," there is an energy flow and it creates momentum"

I don't understand how energy would flow for that system.
and how does energy flow? if it is constantly flowing then it should come/go somewhere right?

Comment: Think about water flowing in a pipe  there is flowing water, but no net gain or loss of water in any region

Answer (score 1):

The poynting vector is a measure of the rate at which energy  flows in a certain direction, per unit area.

For static fields;$$\nabla \cdot \vec{S} = 0$$

This means the rate at which energy leaves a volume is the same as the rate at which energy enters that volume.

$$\iint \vec{S} \cdot \vec{da} = 0$$

Energy is flowing, however there is no net energy gain in any region. Think about water flowing in a pipe  there is flowing water, but no net gain or loss of water in any region.

**Why is this important?**

It seems  pointless to assert there is a flow of energy, but no energy gain in any region, since this is not measurable.

However the momentum of the EM field is proportional to this poynting vector, and without it, Momentum would not he conserved.

For example a charged ring rotating when a  magnetic field decreases to $0$ from some $B_{0}$, the momentum has to come from somewhere, which comes from the EM field.

Comment: there is ambiguity not just involving the Poynting vector but involving the energy distribution in space. Experimentally we can only measure the total work done and total heat flowing in/out during an arrangement of charges, currents and magnets. Unlike the free energy of a body that by itself lacks physical significance, its entropy is absolute.

Comment: you can add an arbitrary solenoidal vector field $\mathbf v = \nabla \times \mathbf g$, and $\mathbf g$ arbitrary, to the Poynting vector and affecting nothing that is measurable.

Comment: Performing the gauge transformations $$U_{E+B} \rightarrow U_{E+B} + \nabla \cdot f$$ $$ \vec{S} \rightarrow \vec{S} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$$  Leave Poyntings theorem invariant

Comment: So can I curve the flow of energy? if I do that would that exert a force since I changed momentum?

Comment: I can have a poynting vector that rotates like a circle, much like the magnetic field of a wire. This doesn't mean that there is a force. The force on a particle is dependant on the maxwell stress tensor  aswell as the time derivative of the poynting vector, there can be spacial curving  without effecting its time derivative.